# Как сделать вместо скролла номера страниц?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть блок данных с скроллом. Я хочу вместо скроллинга, перелистывать страницы. Хотелось бы глянуть на пример реальзации этого. Спасибо. 
[image: Вот так]

Comment: ну это типа слайдер получается

Comment: @MaximLensky: не совсем. Это больше из разряда меню и якорей.

Comment: @UModeL суть не поменяется наверно...

Comment: Да, слайдер  - это горизонтальный скролл как бы, а мне нужны отдельные страницы. Получается при нажатии на следующую страницу, текущий блок скрыть и отрисовывать новую.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23429243/6339052 вот например

Comment: Слишком мало данных в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну попробую так объяснить: есть блок с 100 карточками чего либо, пусть будет какой-то товар. Этот блок из-за своей длинны имеет скролл. Мне нужно убрать этот скролл и сделать так чтобы появились как бы странички. Допустим 10 страниц, на каждой по 10 карточек товара. Надеюсь так понятней.

Comment: `overflow-y: hidden` + сдвиг контента относительно контейнера при помощи js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
location.hash = location.hash || "p1"
```

```css
body { text-align: center; }
section { display: none; }
:target { display: block; }
p { border: 1px solid; margin: 8px 0; }
```

```html
<section id="p1"><p>1.1<p>1.2<p>1.3<p>1.4<p>1.5</section>
<section id="p2"><p>2.1<p>2.2<p>2.3<p>2.4<p>2.5</section>
<section id="p3"><p>3.1<p>3.2<p>3.3<p>3.4<p>3.5</section>
<section id="p4"><p>4.1<p>4.2<p>4.3<p>4.4<p>4.5</section>
<section id="p5"><p>5.1<p>5.2<p>5.3<p>5.4<p>5.5</section>
<section id="p6"><p>6.1<p>6.2<p>6.3<p>6.4<p>6.5</section>
<section id="p7"><p>7.1<p>7.2<p>7.3<p>7.4<p>7.5</section>
<section id="p8"><p>8.1<p>8.2<p>8.3<p>8.4<p>8.5</section>

<a href="#p1">1</a>
<a href="#p2">2</a>
<a href="#p3">3</a>
<a href="#p4">4</a>
<a href="#p5">5</a>
<a href="#p6">6</a>
<a href="#p7">7</a>
<a href="#p8">8</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как пример технологий, которые делают нашу жизнь приятнее. Назовем это "слайдер на css". Есть нюанс, что скорее подход для мобильных устройств, но для саморазвития тоже будет полезно. Используется **scroll-snap-type** анонсированный Chrome, кажется, в начале года. Лучше смотреть на экранах от 1920. В других разрешениях не проверял:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #F0F0C9;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overscroll-behavior-x: contain;
  -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.wrapper .item {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper article {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 50px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.wrapper article h2 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.wrapper article hr {
  height: 6px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.wrapper article hr:last-child {
  margin-right: 60%;
}
.wrapper article hr.image {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.navi {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
 <a href="#1">1</a>
 <a href="#2">2</a>
 <a href="#3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="item" id="1">
  <h4>Items #1</h4>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="item" id="2">
  <h4>Items #2</h4>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
 </div>
 <div class="item" id="3">
  <h4>Items #3</h4>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
  <article>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
   <hr>
  </article>
 </div>
</div>
```